# Existence of continued fraction $\sqrt{n}$ with any period $k$

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions, open-problem

In this paper it is conjectured that for any positive integer $k$ there are infinitely many primes $p$ with the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{p}$ having length $k$ (Conjecture 5.1, https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/mathlab/public_html/jr02fall/Periodicity/alexajp.pdf )

Do we have the weaker result that for any positive integer $k$ there **exists at least one** prime $p$ with the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{p}$ having length $k$ ?

Or perhaps relax the restriction of prime $p$ to any positive integer $n$ ?

Comment: To give you some idea of what you're up against, the continued fraction for $\sqrt n$ has period one if and only if $n=m^2+1$ for some $m$. It is widely believed, but not yet proved, that there are infinitely many $m$ such that $m^2+1$ is prime. My guess is that if you forget about primes it may not be hard to prove that for any $k$ there are infinitely many $n$ such that the period of $\sqrt n$ is $k$. E.g., the period length is two for any $n=m^2-1$.

Comment: For that general question (with unrestricted $n$), see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3427704/simple-continued-fraction-of-sqrtd-with-period-of-shortest-length-3

Comment: Have you followed that link, 651267?

Comment: I'm trying to help you, 651267; you could do me the courtesy of a response.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes I have followed that link. sorry for the late response.

Comment: I'm actually only interested in the positive integer case and not really interested in the prime case, so your link has clarified what I wanted. Thank you.